# htaccess search query

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

In the .htaccess file (apache) how would I change a rewrite search query:

```
test.com/search?q=cats
```

to

```
 test.com/Search?q=cats
```

Capitalize the 'S' in search.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already using mod_rewrite or want to use it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase "/"
RewriteRule ^search Search
```

To make it externally visible it needs to be an external redirect:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase "/"
RewriteRule ^search Search [R,L]
```

Alternatively you can redirect with a simpler directive:

```
Redirect 301 /search /Search
```

Comment: Just added the RewriteRule, and it didn't change. This is a Wordpress site.

Comment: Does the .htaccess file already include RewriteRule directives? If so please edit your question to include its contents.

Comment: Perfect, the simple 301 /search /Search worked! Thanks!

Comment: In htaccess, the first parameter of the rewriterule will never match ^/

Comment: @covener: examples on the rewrite wiki show ```^/``` should match. https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString

Comment: They are guaranteed to not match. The wiki says the contents require mods to work on htaccess.

Comment: @BigWater: If this solved your problem, please select it as the answer.